# How do I use a Public Key Certificate that is stored in Key Vault in an Azure Service Environment and configure this from the DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, client-certificates, azure-app-service-envrmnt

When connecting to an API from an Azure Function or Web App I can upload the public key certificate (.cer file) to the LocalMachine store of the App and add the thumbprints to the configuration using the key "WEBSITE_LOAD_ROOT_CERTIFICATES". When doing this with a self signed certitifcate for an internal organisational API I usually have to specify the Root and Intermediate thumbrints and upload the Root and Intermediate certificate to the Function App.

I like the idea of having the organisational self signed certificates stored in Key Vault so the API that is secured can use the certificate and the consumers of the API can just grab the public key during their deployment.

Is there a way to store these certificates in KeyVault, reference them from an Azure Function (or equivalent) so that I do not have to manually load the certificates and associate them with the HttpClient using code? I like simplicity of using the "WEBSITE_LOAD_ROOT_CERTIFICATES" configuration key.

I would like to configure this in the Azure Devops Pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I use a Public Key Certificate that is stored in Key Vault in an Azure Service Environment and configure this from the DevOps Pipeline?

First create a `Azure Key Vault`  and provide the required `access policies` to retrieve the `Secrets` or `Certificates`.

For this , we need `Service Principal`.

Create [`Service Principal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create) using the `Azure CLI` command.

```cs
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name MyServicePrincipal --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/YourSubscriptionID/resourceGroups/YourRGName/Providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/YourKeyVaultName
```

Next Provide the `Access Policies`.

[image]

- Under `Certificate permissions`, select the operation based on your requirement.

[image]

- Select the `Service Principal` which you have created and continue with next steps to  `Create an access policy`.

> Is there a way to store these certificates in KeyVault, reference them from an Azure Function (or equivalent)

Yes, we can use `Azure Functions` to retrieve the Certificate from Key Vault.

Install the NuGet packages.

```cs
Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets
Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication
```

> configure this from the DevOps Pipeline?

We can use the `Azure CLI` or `Powershell` command in the Azure Pipelines to get the `Certificate`.

Use [`Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-9.4.0), in the Pipeline.

```
-  task:  AzureKVCertificates@5 
  inputs:  
  azureSubscription:  <azure-subscription-name>  
  ScriptType:  InlineScript  
  Inline:  | 
  Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName KVName -Name CertificateName
```

***OR***

We can use `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` by providing the thumbprint values.

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [retrieve Azure Key Vault Secrets using Azure Functions](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/how-to-retrieve-azure-key-vault-secrets-using-azure-functions-part-i)